# Is there a way of unzipping a list of nested redundant list?

Tags: python-3.x, list-manipulation

I have this list:

```
input = [[[1,2]], [[3,4]], [[5,6]]]
```

Wanted output:

```
output = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
```

I have tried this:

```
x, y = map(list,zip(*input))
```

to later realize that this method wont work because of the redundant square brackets,
is there a way to solve this without iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> input = [[[1,2]], [[3,4]], [[5,6]]]
>>> list(zip(*map(itemgetter(0), input)))
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [117]: input = [[[1,2]], [[3,4]], [[5,6]]]

In [118]: list(zip(*[i[0] for i in input]))
Out[118]: [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]

In [119]: list(map(list, zip(*[i[0] for i in input])))
Out[119]: [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```